# Accessing malloc'd function in another file

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

How to access a malloc'ed element in an function that is present in another file

file1.c

```
#include<xyz.h> //all header files

extern struct SomeDefaultStructurefromHeader *str;

void myfunction(){
    str = (struct SomeDefaultStructurefromHeader*)malloc(sizeof(struct SomeDefaultStructurefromHeader));
    str->element1 = 1;
    str->element2 = 2;
}
```

How to I access the str values in another file say file2.c. My Idea was to to create a new element of SomeDefaultStructurefromHeader and then pointing str somehow to it. Would the use of extern help here if declared str as extern and then calling it in file 2

For eg:
file2.c

```
struct SomeDefaultStructurefromHeader *st1;
void func2(){
    st1 = (struct SomeDefaultStructurefromHeader*)malloc(sizeof(struct SomeDefaultStructurefromHeader));
    st1 = str;
    printf(st1->element1) // this might return the value str->element1 which is 1
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: `st1 = str;` is memory leak.

Comment: Are you compiling C or C++? You should not cast `malloc` in C. And really, pass the address of a pointer or return a pointer instead of relying on global variables.

Comment: For declaration use one common header (`.h`) file. And to copy structure use `memcpy`.

Answer (score 3):

You should declare it in file1.c like this:

```
struct SomeDefaultStructurefromHeader *str;
```

and in file2.c add the extern specifier:

```
extern struct SomeDefaultStructurefromHeader *str;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare in file2.c as well as:

```
extern struct SomeDefaultStructurefromHeader *str;
```

However, in one of the C file you must define global variable as:

```
struct SomeDefaultStructurefromHeader *str;
```